# Entering text in snippet fields uses wrong character when using langmap

Tags: vim, snipmate

I am using a custom keymap using `langmap` option in vimrc.

I am trying to use snipmate but I am running into trouble. When I type a word and hit tab it allows me to edit the parameter. The problem is that the first character is the remapped one, while I want it to be the actual key.

For instance, I'll type this:

```
for
```

and hit tab to expand the snippet:

```
for (i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i)
```

The `i` is highlighted which means I can edit it. I type "aaa":

```
for (baa = 0; i < COUNT; ++i)
```

It comes out `baa` even though I typed `aaa`. This is because I remapped `a` and `b`.

How can I fix this?

---

Here is my keymapping:

```
set langmap=nj,N},ek,E{,il,IL,{^,}$,lb,LB,uw,UW,ye,YE,jg,JG,\\;z,f\\.,F\\,,zu,ZU,.?,\\,/,/v,?    V,ta,TA,si,SI,ro,RO,ac,AC,wr,WR,xx,XX,dd,DD,bs,BS,gf,GF,pt,PT,kn,KN,cy,CY,vp,VP,o\\;
```

It won't make much sense to others, and I haven't finalized how I want it to look.

Comment: What did you expect? aaa? bbb? Why would you want to remap a and b? Please provide your custom keymap so that we know to what you remapped a and b.

Comment: Could you paste your exact mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C program which outputs mappings similar behavior to langmap but not for select:

```
/* input:
lhs rhs optional-descripton
lhs rhs ...
*/

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  FILE *fi = fopen("in.txt", "r");
  FILE *fo = fopen("out.txt", "w");
  char lc[8], rc[8];
  while (fscanf(fi, "\n%s %s", lc, rc) != EOF) {
    fprintf(fo, "nnoremap %s %s\n", lc, rc);
    fprintf(fo, "xnoremap %s %s\n", lc, rc);
    fprintf(fo, "onoremap %s %s\n", lc, rc);
    while (fgetc(fi) != '\n');
  }
  fclose(fo);
  fclose(fi);
}
```

It doesn't work identically to langmap and so it might break other bindings.

Answer (score 2):

From your `:set langmap` I understand that you mapped `a` to `c` so, by typing `aaa`, did you expect to obtain `ccc`?

From what I understand (`:help langmap`), your custom substitutions are not available in *INSERT* mode for actually inserting stuff and I don't see a mention of the *SELECT* mode you are in when overwriting SnipMate's placeholders.

If I do this

```
:set langmap+=ac,bs
```

and I type `aaa` in *SELECT* mode, I obtain `caa`.

That's because `langmap` applies to the first `a` (`:help Select-mode`) and, therefore inserts `c`. But, after this first character I am in *INSERT* mode for all subsequent characters. Since `langmap` doesn't apply in *INSERT* mode, `aa` is inserted as is.

What is not clear to me is why you obtain `baa` instead of `caa`. Your `langmap` seems to be pretty clear about your intention: you want `a` to insert `c` and `b` to insert `s`. Typing `a` shouldn't insert `b`.

I smell a risk of mistyping in your `.vimrc`. Try this: reset your `set langmap` and start adding your mappings one by one.

May I ask you what is the purpose of such a massive remapping?

Comment: The `baa` was more for illustrative purposes. You're correct in that it's really `caa`. I'm using a custom mapping as I'm using a different keyboard layout. I tried using `snoremap` in vimrc, which does work, although it's a mess to do this for every key.

Comment: What keyboard layout do you use?

Comment: Colemak. The langmap is completely different from a normal vim layout though. I think I'll just write a program to do the remapping instead of doing it by hand.

Comment: I've seen it, but I'm not a big fan. It uses wasd-style movement, and other silliness.

Answer (score 0):

This has now been fixed in vim 7.4.1150. See
https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/572
for details.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know